# Method will be shown automatically with the try catch block in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, methods, try-catch

In Eclipse there is the option to set a method will be created along with try catch block or not.

What will i do get the same thing in android studio.

How i did the thing in eclipse will explained below,

[image]

help me to do the above thing in android studio.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

- Highlight the code
- Press "Code-> Surround With"
- In the list, type "try"

There's also a keyboard shortcut, You can get it from your menu.

Comment: i'm asking about the method always comes with an try catch block automatically the eclipse have the option so thats why i'm asking the same is reside in the android studio or not.                                                                                                                                                                                                                             i know the "Ctrl+Alt+T"  will ask the sourrend with option.i'm not asking that

Comment: reply me i need to do